# Disable Facebook account but keep Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I would like to disable my Facebook account, but keep using Facebook Messenger to keep in touch with some of my friends.

There are even some tutorials (and not so old), which describe how to do it (e.g. [here](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/internet/social-media/fed-up-of-facebook-but-want-to-keep-messenger-heres-how-to-do-it-11364068930697)), however if I follow them, when I log in again in Messenger (and it does not matter if I do it in the phone app or on messenger.com), I get the email from Facebook stating, that my account was reactivated.

Is there some trick for this I am missing? Or did Facebook just remove this possibility to make quiting Facebook more complicated?

Comment: I doubt it's possible. The accounts are tied together. It'd be like trying to throw away your cell phone but still using it to call someone. Let me ask; why do you want to disable the account? You mentioned why you want to keep messenger, which makes a lot of sense, but why delete the account? You could really amp up your security settings instead?

Comment: It makes sense to me that it would not be possible, but there are so many tutorials about that, that I just had to ask. I don't use Facebook any more, but I use Messenger and if I have disabled the account, it would be more clear to the people on Facebook that I don't use it.